# How can I force maven to leave the version number out of dependency file names?

Tags: java, maven-2

I'm using maven to build a ".ear" project that resolves dependencies from a maven repository, and then packages them into an ear (that's probably a redundant sentence...).

When the dependencies show up in the ear file, they're named according to this format:

```
<artifactId>-<version>.<type>
```

I'd like them to be named:

```
<artifactId>.<type>
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using the maven-assembly-plugin to build your ear, you can use the `outputFileNameMapping` property in your descriptor: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html#class_dependencySet

However, you're probably better off using the maven-ear-plugin, in which case you can customize the `bundleFileName`, as described [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/examples/customizing-a-module-filename.html).

Comment: The maven-ear-plugin requires that I add a bundleFileName for each and every dependent, correct?  (I can't specify a pattern that should apply to all of them unless I use maven-assembly-plugin).

Comment: yep, that's my understanding.  Although, with the ear plugin, you're technically specifying the modules that you're adding to the ear, not dependencies.

Comment: Good answer. I ended up using `<outputFileNameMapping>${artifact.build.finalName}.${artifact.extension}</outputFileNameMapping>` and in other project `<outputFileNameMapping>${artifact.name}.${artifact.extension}</outputFileNameMapping>`.

Comment: If you'd just like to strip down the version from file name: <outputFileNameMapping>${artifact.artifactId}.${artifact.extension}</outputFileNameMapping>

Answer (score 1):

Set the finalName property.  See http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly-mojo.html for more details

Comment: This lets me change the name of the final ear file output (which is nice and all,) but what I really want to do is change the name of the dependencies that are inside the ear file, not the ear file itself.  (or am I misunderstanding?)