# How can I force maven WAR plugin to leave the version number out of dependency file names?

Tags: maven, dependencies, version, war

I'm facing the same issue described here: [How can I force maven to leave the version number out of dependency file names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709290/how-can-i-force-maven-to-leave-the-version-number-out-of-dependency-file-names) but with the WAR plugin. Looked around but didn't find any solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define [file name mappings](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/file-name-mapping.html) with the `maven-war-plugin`. This is done with the [`outputFileNameMapping`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html#outputFileNameMapping) of the plugin configuration:

```xml
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
        <outputFileNameMapping>@{artifactId}@.@{extension}@</outputFileNameMapping>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

With this configuration, each dependency in `WEB-INF/lib` will be stripped of their version.

Comment: I'm not looking for the finalName, I'm looking for the dependency file name like this WEB-INF/lib/mydependency-1.3.0.jar, I would like to remove the 1.3.0 part.

Comment: @ThiagoLeãoMoreira I misunderstood your question then, I edited to reflect your use-case. You should perhaps update the question to make it more clear.